# Facebook API. Notification via social plugin comments

Tags: php, facebook

I have a page with a [comments social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), I would like to know if it's possible to notify users who have already commented on the form.

I can subscribe to the `comment.create` function, but how do I send notifications?

I know actual notifications are now impossible, but is there another way? (Sending a message from the user perhaps?). With the format of my page, they will want to know when someone has posted.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried that, it's just an idea.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ - look at the section describing way of getting comments via Graph API.

**E-mail way:**
You can ask each user who logs into your site to allow you to get his e-mail address. Then, you would subscribe to this event, list users who commented an article and send them an e-mail.

**Message way:**
You need a Facebook page for your site. Then you would receive a token for this page (`manage_pages` permission), get `publish_stream` permission in behalf of this page and publish message to streams of users who commented.

It may be also possible to send user a message on behalf of a page using Graph API, however I haven't seen anything like that in docs

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed by facebook, the attempt will result something like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

This is because the social plugins do not "live" inside facebook, they are being distributed to 3rd party sites, and to prevent bad content posted from bots/apps to display in 3rd party websites, facebook has disabled this option.

Answer (score 0):

Search for WordPress Plugin called ***Ultimate Facebook Comments Email Notify***. I hope it will solve your problem...and you can also take some idea from his script which he is using in the plugin....hope this helps :)